# CSS max-width has no effect; width used instead

Tags: html, css, width

I'm trying to set an element to be a certain size in pixels, or, if that exceeds a certain percentage of the screen, that percentage of the screen.

I looked around and it seemed like `max-width` should do the trick, but it doesn't.

The relevant CSS is:

```
ul.images {
  width: 10000px;  
  max-width: 10%;
}
```

10000 is much bigger than 100%, hence the width should be 10%, but it just uses 10,000 instead. This is in Chrome. How can I fix this?

Comment: Works perfectly fine in Chrome here, what's inside the `ul`, or around it? You should probably add some HTML before anyone can help. If you for example have a `div` with `width: 10000px` which contains the `ul`, then the desribed behaviour would make perfect sense, or if you had an image inside it with that width specified.

Comment: @user1846192: The ul has a bunch of images. Note that when I do `width: 10%` it works perfectly fine (i.e. it's 10% of the width)..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because of a

```
display: table;
```

in the CSS.

Removing that fixed it for some reason.

Comment: Maybe next time you could post a bit more CSS and HTML, so we don't have to guess what might or might not be the problem. Adding an answer like this doesn't really help the next person that finds this question. Where was this `display: table`? Parent or child element?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you might be experiencing has more to do with the `padding` and `margin` of the `ul` and `html, body`.

Does this fix you problem? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4GUv/1/)

```
html, body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
ul.images {
  width: 10000px;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

If this fixes your issue, then `max-width` works perfectly fine, the only problem you were having is that the `max-width: 100%`, in combination with the `padding` and the `margin` of the `ul` and its containing elements, is wider than `100%`.

Comment: Hmm, tried and still no effect. Note that I'm trying `max-width: 10%`, i.e. it should be much smaller than 100% anyway. And again, if I set `width: 10%` directly without going through `max-width` then it works fine, hence I said `max-width` doesn't do what it is supposed to do (i.e. override `width` if it's smaller than it).

Comment: actually, just tried `max-width: 50px`, which doesn't have any effect either

Comment: `max-width` is not supposed to override `width` if it is smaller than it, that is what `min-width` is for, in any case, if I set `max-width` to `10%` or `100%` in the jsFiddle, it does exactly what it is supposed to do and totally ignore the `width` of `10000px`, and I'm on Chrome 26.

Answer (score 0):

Is the parent container of your ul positioned fixed/absolutely with no specified width?
I have created a fiddle with some example code, and it worked fine when the ul wasn't the child of an absolute parent AND the parent had a specified width, but didn't work when it was.

http://jsbin.com/imazaq/2/edit

Comment: You've got a point here, if I set the `body, html` to `position: absolute;` in my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4GUv/2/), things stop working too. Exactly why I asked for some HTML earlier :)

Comment: just checked and no there are no such elements